# mp3 streaming works on windows phone 7 .x but not on windows phone 8 devices

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, streaming

I am working on an internet radio app for windows phone 8. 
I've been adding "Stream.mp3" to my shoutcast url in order to get the stream as an mp3 file eg. "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0000/; file.mp3".

my samples stream is 
1)radyo.ersu.net:3400/;stream.mp3
2)5.172.194.10:9996/;file.mp3

This is working fine on my windows phone 7.x device.

However, I tried testing it on Windows phone 8 phones and it is not working.

Any idea what is happening?

thanks !

```
protected override void OnUserAction(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, UserAction action, object param)
    {
        player = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance;
        try
        {
            switch (action)
            {
                case UserAction.Play:
                    if (player.PlayerState != PlayState.Playing)
                    {

                        player.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://5.172.194.10:9996/; file.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), "Radio name", null, null, null);
                        player.Volume = 1;
                        player.Play();

                    }
                    break;
                case UserAction.Stop:
                    player.Stop();
                    break;
                case UserAction.Pause:
                    player.Pause();
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (SystemException)
        { }

        NotifyComplete();
    }
```

Comment: Hello, did you work out why it was not working?